# should I use the ruby that comes with my mac or should I install the newer versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Is it recommended to use the ruby that came with my Mac or should I install later versions?

I'm doing an online tutorial to help me learn and going through installations can be difficult and time-consuming and I want to get to the fun stuff.

Comment: You probably want to install a specific Ruby version sooner or later, but to get started, the version that came with your Mac (Ruby 2.0.0) should be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not recommended. *There is no situation* in which you would be advised to use older than the newest stable version.

So always tend to get the newest stable version of Ruby/Rails, unless you have compatibility issues.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your advice. It's very useful and I have already found tutorials to properly make sure to install the current versions. But now this raises the question, why bother to make computers with the language already pre-installed if it is not the recommended way most developers work?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most flexible solution is using a ruby version manager, like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). These tools permits you to have multiple versions of ruby at the same time. So you can have several ruby projects, that run on different ruby version, and you'll have no problem.

Comment: With the added caveat that you should leave the system Ruby alone: ignore the system-suppled version, install your own via rvm/rbenv somewhere in your home directory and use your own. Otherwise you could screw up system scripts (that may or may not exist) that depend on a certain version.

Comment: Yes I know but this is often a must. I worked in a company where I had to keep like ten versions of ruby because there were so many projects that need different versions.

Comment: And even if you leave the professional environment. Let's say the user starts a ruby book that use a different version.

Comment: Let alone different versions of the same project.

Comment: I worked for an agency and there was no way it would have worked without one of these. My personal preference is rbenv on my machine and rvm on servers. Both work great. Only use one on your machine, though.